# How to resolve the 'cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: gherkin.ParserException$CompositeParserException: Parser errors:' issue in cucumber

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

**Feature File:**

```
Feature: Claims Regression suit scenarios using BDD
@Test
Scenario: Log in to AUT as ClaimAssistant with valid credential.
Given Browser is launched successfully
```

**Step Definition File :**

```
@Given("^Browser is launched successfully$")
    public void Browser_is_launched_successfully() throws InterruptedException, IOException
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "U:\\Claims Jar\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
```

**Test Runner Class File :**

```
package Runner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features="Feature",
        glue={"stepDefn"},
        plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber-reports"},
        tags="@CO_Login_Test_ClaimAssistant"  ,
        dryRun= true ,
        monochrome = true
        )public class TestRunner {}
```

Comment: Can you provide the full stacktrace in your question? It will likely point to the place in your Gherkin file which cannot be parsed.